# Upgraded Target Framework from 4.7 to 4.7.1 Nu-Get cannot restore packages

Tags: .net, nuget-package-restore

I just changed the target framework of all 11 projects in my Visual Studio 2017 solution from .NET 4.7 to .NET 4.7.1.   But now, every single time I try to build, I get the following error from NuGet

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GS.Core, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5): error : Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
StopOnFirstBuildError: Build cancelled because project "GS.Core" failed to build.
Build has been canceled.
```

If I look in the .csproj file, I do see that the target framework has changed.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

And I don't see a "TargetFrameworks" section, just "TargetFrameworkVersion"

Just for laughs I tried actually adding a key with that name, exactly as the error message specified.

```
<TargetFrameworks>.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

That was a bad idea.  Visual Studio exploded when I tried to load it.

My default package management format is "PackageReference", if that matters.

I tried the fix listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023982/nuget-re-targeting-after-upgrading-from-net-framework-4-5-to-4-6-1), but that had no effect.

Is there a way to fix this?  I'm happy to manually edit project files if necessary.  I would very much like to go to 4.7.1

Comment: That looks like a .NETCore build error message.  Well, good match for a project named "GS.Core", you probably shouldn't try to target .NETFramework.  .NETCore does it differently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: Hi Hans.  Actually all of my projects target the standard .NET Framework.  I realize the name is "Core" but that's just a coincidence.  I've been using this project with .NET 4.7 for over a year now

Answer (score 21):

Answering my own question because after a great deal of googling, I stumbled on the answer on on the MS developer community forum

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/317628/your-project-does-not-reference-netframeworkversio.html

The culprit appears to be a project.assets.json file in the .OBJ folder.  The workaround is to delete all the bin and .OBJ folders and rebuild.  MS notes that since there is a workaround, this a low-priority problem.

Note that cleaning the solution did not help.  I had to manually delete the folders.  I guess the json file isn't considered a part of the build, even though it lives there.

(I should say I cannot say definitively that was literally .json file.  I deleted the folders once I saw the recommendation and never looked for one.  But I'm guessing that's ti).

Comment: Can't imagine this is the solution. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I have made a PowerShell script for the same which will delete bin and obj folder from every project: Just Run this at solution level folder.                                 
1. Get-ChildItem bin -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }    
2. Get-ChildItem obj -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }

Comment: Its important to delete more than the Startup project bin/obj folders. I did that first, and it didnt help. I had to go into the referenced project and delete the folders there, not in the outout folder for the startup project.