# How to update Visual Studio packages in nuget?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package

In Visual Studio, I changed the build target from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 and get this warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning
>   Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more information.  Packages affected: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, System.Buffers, System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, System.Memory, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe  InquiryWeb

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023982/nuget-re-targeting-after-upgrading-from-net-framework-4-5-to-4-6-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retargeting solution from .Net 4.0 to 4.5 - how to retarget the NuGet packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006991/retargeting-solution-from-net-4-0-to-4-5-how-to-retarget-the-nuget-packages)