# Run Update-Package -Reinstall in Rider

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, rider, nuget-package-manager-console

I need to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023982/nuget-re-targeting-after-upgrading-from-net-framework-4-5-to-4-6-1/40681448#40681448), but I don't use VisualStudio.

The stated solution (on that question, elsewhere, and also from work colleagues) is `Update-Package -Reinstall`.

But that pre-supposes the existence of PackageManagerConsole ... which AFAIK doesn't exist in Rider (there's an EF management console available, but not (to my knowledge) a more general Nuget one)

How do I:

- run that command, or the equivalent, in Rider?
- run that command from a cmd line outside of any IDE (i.e. outside of / without VisualStudio)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/resources/nuget-faq#can-i-use-nuget-outside-of-visual-studio-

Comment: Except there doesn't seem to be anything matching the -Reinstall parameter in their CLI reference :(

Comment: Any update on this? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the official document of the Update-Package command:

[Update-Package (Package Manager Console in Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-update-package)

> Available only within the NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual
> Studio on Windows.
>
> Updates a package and its dependencies, or all packages in a project,
> to a newer version.

And from the comment of the -reinstall argument, you can see:

> Reinstall the same version of the original package, but with the latest version of dependencies (subject to version constraints). If this command rolls a dependency back to an earlier version, use Update-Package <dependency_name> to reinstall that one dependency without affecting the dependent package.

so I think the mutual aim feature in nuget.exe should be:

'nuget restore' and 'nuget update'.

**[restore command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore)**

> Downloads and installs any packages missing from the packages folder.
> When used with NuGet 4.0+ and the PackageReference format, generates a
> .nuget.props file, if needed, in the obj folder. (The file
> can be omitted from source control.)

**[update command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-update)**

> Updates all packages in a project (using packages.config) to their
> latest available versions. It is recommended to run 'restore' before
> running the update. (To update an individual package, use nuget
> install without specifying a version number, in which case NuGet
> installs the latest version.)
>
> The update command also updates assembly references in the project
> file, provided those references already exist. If an updated package
> has an added assembly, a new reference is not added. New package
> dependencies also don't have their assembly references added. To
> include these operations as part of an update, update the package in
> Visual Studio using the Package Manager UI or the Package Manager
> Console.

## Remember to configure the nuget command exe to system env variable path.